# Android on Kotlin: How to pass data from an Activity to an event listener?

Tags: android, kotlin

(Android newbie learning Kotlin here...) I have an app with 3 components: A UI activity where a user indicates what color car she wants to see; A service that uses the device's camera to observe a road and report every car that passes by; And an event listener latched on the service. The job of the event listener is to determine whether any car reported by the camera is of the requested color and, if so, do something about it.

I'm tripping over something that's probably basic: how does the listener know what color to look for? I can:

1. Have the activity (a class) write to a variable owned by the listener (an object) (hmmm...)
2. Have the activity drop the color in an event bus (does it have to be so complicated?)
3. Have the listener reach over and read a screen variable (hmmm...)
4. Use some global variable in some singleton (hmmm...)

What's the proper way to do this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can take help of the Shared preferences to store the value(i.e color)or you can do as you mentioned in the 4th point.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).